# Duplicating a unity class that is connected to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, service, unity-container

TIA

Full Disclosure - I am new to ASP.NET web development and I am still learning some of the framework and it's interactions. I will try to guard my statements here and identify ones that I am not sure I am using correctly.

I am working with an open source package that I downloaded called BeYourMarket  where I have a payment controller that has a service. I am not sure exactly what this means, but I believe it has something to do with Unity? This service seems to control order related items on the site. It is connected to a table in the database that is being used in the entire website. I believe that Entity Framework is providing the conduit for this.

Here is code snippets of what I am trying to duplicate instead of it managing Orders this duplication will manage Token Orders. The ellipse's are my way of showing that there is code in between.

I suspect there is something I fundamentally do not understand here.

Below is the controller which you can see I duplicated the OrderService

```
PaymentController.cs
{
    [Authorize]
    public class PaymentController : Controller
    {
        ...
        private readonly IOrderService _orderService;
        private readonly IOrderServiceToken _orderServiceToken;
        ...
    }
    public PaymentController(
        ...
        IOrderService orderService,
        IOrderServiceToken orderServiceToken,)
        {
        ...
        _orderService = orderService;         
        _orderServiceToken = orderServiceToken;
        ...
        }
}
```

Below are the files/classes I created a duplicate from

BeYourMarket.Service\OrderService.cs

```
public interface IOrderService : IService<Order>
{
}

public class OrderService : Service<Order>, IOrderService
{
    public OrderService(IRepositoryAsync<Order> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {
    }
}
```

BeYourMarket.Models\Models\Order.cs

```
{
    public partial class Order : Repository.Pattern.Ef6.Entity
    {
        public Order()
        {
            this.ListingReviews = new List<ListingReview>();
        }
        ...
        public int DataBaseVariable { get; set; }
        ...           
    }
}
```

BeYourMarket.Model\Models\Mapping\OrderMap.cs

```
    public class OrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
    {
        public OrderMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

            // Properties
            ...

            this.Property(t => t.PaymentPlugin)
                .HasMaxLength(250);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("Orders");
           ...
            this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

It might be worth noting that below my DbSet never gets ran.  Perhaps I need to do some sort of another Initial setup that was ran when I first launched this package.  I have no understanding how to run this 'setup' again.

BeYourMarket.Model\Models\BeYourMarketContext.cs

```
public BeYourMarket()
    : base("Name=DefaultConnection")
{
}

...
public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
public DbSet<OrderToken> OrderToken { get; set; }
...

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderTokenMap());
    }
```

BeYourMarket.Service\DataCacheService.cs

```
public class DataCacheService
{
...
        private IOrderService OrderService
    {
        get { return _container.Resolve<IOrderService>(); }
    }

    private IOrderServiceToken OrderServiceToken
    {
        get { return _container.Resolve<IOrderServiceToken>(); }
    }
...
}
```

Attached here is an image of the error I get. If I replace the `<OrderToken>` class in my `OrderSErviceToken.cs` with any other already created database for instance the `<Order>` everything works fine. It has something to do with me manually creating all this and missing some link or registration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpzBS.jpg)

Thanks for reading if you were able to stick through it this long.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I overlooked a line I needed to duplicate inside the following file:

-Note the line that I forgot is the line with asterisks.

UnityConfig.cs

```
.RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<Order>, Repository<Order>>()
**.RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<OrderToken>, Repository<OrderToken>>()**
...
.RegisterType<IOrderService, OrderService>()
.RegisterType<IOrderServiceToken, OrderServiceToken>()
```